# How to sort date by descending order and time by ascending order using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My `df` looks like this. It is an `hourly` dataset.

```
time                    Open
2017-01-03 09:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 08:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-03 07:00:00     5.2128
2017-01-02 09:00:00     5.4122
2017-01-02 08:00:00     5.2123
2017-01-02 07:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-01 09:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-01 08:00:00     5.2128
2017-01-01 07:00:00     5.4122
```

I want to `sort` the `hourly` only data by `ascending` order.

**What did I do?**

I did:

```
df.sort_values(by='time', ascending=True)
```

but it `sort` entire value of `time` however I want to only `sort` the `time` section.

My new `df` should look like this:

```
time                    Open
2017-01-03 07:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 08:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-03 09:00:00     5.2128
2017-01-02 07:00:00     5.4122
2017-01-02 08:00:00     5.2123
2017-01-02 09:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-01 07:00:00     5.2180
2017-01-01 08:00:00     5.2128
2017-01-01 09:00:00     5.4122
```

Here `date` stays the same but the `time` is in `ascending` order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If need sorting by dates and times create new columns for sorting by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), then sort by both columns with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and ascending parameter, because sorting by `dates` is descending and by times is ascending and last remove helper columns with [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(d=df['time'].dt.date,
                 t=df['time'].dt.time)
         .sort_values(['d','t'], ascending=[False, True])
         .drop(['d','t'], axis=1))
print (df1)
                 time    Open
2 2017-01-03 07:00:00  5.2128
1 2017-01-03 08:00:00  5.2180
0 2017-01-03 09:00:00  5.2475
5 2017-01-02 07:00:00  5.2475
4 2017-01-02 08:00:00  5.2123
3 2017-01-02 09:00:00  5.4122
8 2017-01-01 07:00:00  5.4122
7 2017-01-01 08:00:00  5.2128
6 2017-01-01 09:00:00  5.2180
```

Or if dates cannot be changed and need sorting only by times use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with lambda function - groupby not sorting, because `sort=False` parameter and `group_keys=False` is for avoid `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df['time'].dt.date, sort=False, group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('time')))
print (df1)
                 time    Open
2 2017-01-03 07:00:00  5.2128
1 2017-01-03 08:00:00  5.2180
0 2017-01-03 09:00:00  5.2475
5 2017-01-02 07:00:00  5.2475
4 2017-01-02 08:00:00  5.2123
3 2017-01-02 09:00:00  5.4122
8 2017-01-01 07:00:00  5.4122
7 2017-01-01 08:00:00  5.2128
6 2017-01-01 09:00:00  5.2180
```